# Sql inserting information into several items in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I got this example to work with some help on here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92e87/1

However, if I want to try and insert information for every child of the table, I cant seem to get it to work (using this code):

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
;

CREATE TABLE location (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    coordinate varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    country_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES country (id)
)
;

CREATE TABLE item (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(900) NOT NULL,
    date datetime NOT NULL,
    source varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    link varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES location (id)
)
;

Insert Into item (title) values ('Title');
Insert Into item (description) values ('Description');
Insert Into item (date) values ('1995-12-31T23:59:59Z');
Insert Into item (source) values ('Source');
Insert Into item (link) values ('Link');
Insert Into item (location_id) values ('1');
```

Is this the correct way of doing this? Secondly, it tells me "description" doesnt have a default value, but does it need one if I will always be putting information into it?

Thank you for any help you can give

Comment: Before inserting a row in item table you must have the corresponding entry in location (in the example you need to have a row in location with id=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert Into item (title, description, date, source, link, location_id) 
values ('Title', 'Description','1995-12-31T23:59:59Z','source','Link',1);
```

Each insert acts as inserting a new record. hence you need to combine all data into one insert statement as given above.

The SQL asks for default value, because you have mentioned `NOT NULL` in the table definition which you have created.

Comment: The last value ('1') should be 1 (not quoted) as it's an integer.

Answer (score 2):

For every insert, you will end up with a new row of data in the item table. I do not think this is what you want. Instead, do:

```
INSERT INTO item VALUES (NULL, [title], [description], [date], [source], [link], [location_id]);
```

Replace the items in [ and ] with the appropriate values.

You are being told that Description does not have a default value because in your INSERT statements that don't specify a value for that column, there is no default value that the database can fill in for that field.

Comment: I tried this: 
INSERT INTO item VALUES (NULL, Test Title, Description, Date, Source, Link, 1);

Comment: But it says: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: You still have to quote your strings. For example: INSERT INTO item VALUES (NULL, 'Test Title', 'Description', [date], 'Source', 'Link', 1);

Comment: The date column is of type DATETIME, so you'll need to use an appropriate function to specify that.